# How to sort collection in mongodb with key from another collection?

Tags: mongodb

Our current data model looks like this: A collection 'store' stores a large number of objects (100 000 +). The collection 'list' stores references to the objects in 'store'. The list objects in 'list' can have from a dozen to 10 000s of elements, if not more later on.

How can I sort a list object in 'list' based on fields found in the objects that are referenced? Would a join between the 'list' and 'store' collection in another (temporary) collection be the way to go? Or is the concept of storing references in 'list' objects not a recommended path for mongodb? For example, is holding an array in the 'store' object that contains the list names a better approach?

Comment: You could store the fields on which you sort in the list itself.

Comment: That means basically caching the field in the list collection. That would have to be dynamic, as I do not know upfront which fields the client wants to sort it by.